Trigger lambda only after receiving message in SQS from all datacentres
I have say 4 DC and each generates a message independently and writes to SQS queue. Each DC may have its own delay and may not write at same time as other. DC's can have difference of as large as 5-10 min in writing to SQS.
How can I trigger a lambda after all DC have written the message.

One option is to maintain an atomic counter in DynamoDB, increment it from the Lambda function as each SQS message is received, and configure DynamoDB Streams to trigger a second Lambda function that's triggered on updates to the DynamoDB table. The second Lambda function tests the counter value. Be aware that a given Lambda function can be invoked multiple times (error retries) so you'd need to account for that possibility, to avoid the counter over-counting.

It is not possible to meet your requirement from Amazon SQS alone. You will need to add your own logic somewhere that can identify when a message has been received from each data centre.
